# can we integrating custom filter pipe and pagination in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, pipe, angularjs-filter

I have a component to display a table of date with pagination, sort and filter. I have custom pagination service that slices the data and displays. But my filter and sort pipe only works for the sliced data. Where as it needs to work for the complete JSON data.
Can i have suggestions of how to parse the complete data.
Below is how Iam using the filter pipe and sort pipe.

```
<tbody  *ngFor = "let request of slicedRequestObjects | category: searchText : optionVal | orderBy: convertSorting(); let i = index;" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your filtering comes before the pagination does it work. It sounds like if you have 50 items in a list, your paginator is taking the first 10, and then you are filtering that list of 10 only.

I use a package called ng2-pagination. It functions as a pipe on your *ngFor. I then use this in tandem with a custom pipe I created to do filtering.

It looks something like

```
*ngFor="let item of myList | termFilter:searchTerm | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 15, currentPage: c, id: 'c' }"
```

Comment: I would like to use my custom pagination service to make paginate work.  so i dont want to use the ng2-pagination package.

Comment: That is fine just make sure that your pagination is not happening before your filtering is happening. In my example above you can see that the list if first passed through the filter pipe, and then the pagination pipe ensuring that pagination doesn't strip out everything before filter.

Comment: That works doing filtering and sorting before pagination. Thank you.